# ANR : androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.SystemAlarmService

Tags: android, android-workmanager

ANR for my app on play console with androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.SystemAlarmService

Happening on android 5.0 and 5.1 only as per play console
(mostly on samsung J2 device) but i'm unable to repor

Version used : Work Manager 2.0.1

raised a issue on google as well https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136693256

getting following stacktrace :

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x775b2000 self=0xb4427800
  | sysTid=11690 nice=-4 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f29bec
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=114 stm=53 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe7e4000-0xbe7e6000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000003be40  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  #01  pc 0000000000015923  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+26)
  #02  pc 0000000000015931  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+6)
  #03  pc 00000000000127cf  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+98)
  #04  pc 00000000000129f9  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+92)
  #05  pc 0000000000089149  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvi+22)
  #06  pc 00000000000b780b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:143)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6946)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
"HikePubSubThread" tid=3 Waiting 
"HikePubSubThread" prio=5 tid=3 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00508 self=0xb4429000
  | sysTid=11717 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4519580
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9d48c000-0x9d48e000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x15d637ae> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x15d637ae> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at com.bsb.hike.ay.run (SourceFile:1215)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=4 Waiting 
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c002a0 self=0xb4427400
  | sysTid=11709 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4514080
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb3c19000-0xb3c1b000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x232a862d> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run (Daemons.java:149)
- locked <0x232a862d> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"FinalizerDaemon" tid=5 Waiting 
"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c002f8 self=0xb4427c00
  | sysTid=11710 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4514300
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=12 stm=3 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb3b15000-0xb3b17000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x21cb0762> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:422)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:101)
- locked <0x21cb0762> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:72)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:189)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"Binder_1" tid=6 Native 
"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=6 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00350 self=0xaf067000
  | sysTid=11712 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4514f80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb3919000-0xb391b000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000003b734  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000052c21  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 000000000001f5db  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+138)
  #03  pc 000000000001fadb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+6)
  #04  pc 000000000001fb3d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+48)
  #05  pc 0000000000023ceb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (???)
  #06  pc 00000000000106bd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
  #07  pc 0000000000065db1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+72)
  #08  pc 000000000001022d  /system/lib/libutils.so (???)
  #09  pc 0000000000017667  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  #10  pc 0000000000015687  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=7 Waiting 
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c003a8 self=0xb4428000
  | sysTid=11713 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4514a80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xafaac000-0xafaae000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x177e30f3> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject (Daemons.java:255)
- locked <0x177e30f3> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run (Daemons.java:227)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"Binder_2" tid=8 Native 
"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=8 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00400 self=0xaf068000
  | sysTid=11714 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaf0a0080
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=2 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xaf999000-0xaf99b000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000003b734  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000052c21  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 000000000001f5db  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+138)
  #03  pc 000000000001fadb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+6)
  #04  pc 000000000001fb3d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+48)
  #05  pc 0000000000023ceb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (???)
  #06  pc 00000000000106bd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
  #07  pc 0000000000065db1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+72)
  #08  pc 000000000001022d  /system/lib/libutils.so (???)
  #09  pc 0000000000017667  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  #10  pc 0000000000015687  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
"HeapTrimmerDaemon" tid=9 Waiting 
"HeapTrimmerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=9 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00458 self=0xb4428400
  | sysTid=11715 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4514d00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=13 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xaf895000-0xaf897000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x029711b0> (a java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:326)
- locked <0x029711b0> (a java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"GCDaemon" tid=10 Waiting 
"GCDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=10 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c004b0 self=0xb4428800
  | sysTid=11716 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4519d00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=58 stm=11 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xa26c0000-0xa26c2000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x3fd65829> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run (Daemons.java:359)
- locked <0x3fd65829> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"RxSchedulerPurge-1" tid=11 TimedWaiting 
"RxSchedulerPurge-1" daemon prio=5 tid=11 TimedWaiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00620 self=0xb4429800
  | sysTid=11718 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4519800
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=8 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9d388000-0x9d38a000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0fc0e94f> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x0fc0e94f> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:197)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2055)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1060)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1" tid=12 TimedWaiting 
"RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1" daemon prio=5 tid=12 TimedWaiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00768 self=0xb442a800
  | sysTid=11719 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4519a80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9d284000-0x9d286000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x3e5398dc> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x3e5398dc> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:197)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2055)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1060)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"RxComputationThreadPool-1" tid=13 Waiting 
"RxComputationThreadPool-1" daemon prio=5 tid=13 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c008b0 self=0xb4435800
  | sysTid=11720 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb4514800
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=51 stm=13 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9d180000-0x9d182000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x215220ba> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x215220ba> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"RxComputationThreadPool-2" tid=14 Waiting 
"RxComputationThreadPool-2" daemon prio=5 tid=14 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c009f8 self=0xb47e1c00
  | sysTid=11723 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb451ac00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=35 stm=9 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9d07c000-0x9d07e000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x3fcccb6b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x3fcccb6b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"HikeBranchSdkInit" tid=15 Waiting 
"HikeBranchSdkInit" daemon prio=5 tid=15 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00b40 self=0xaf069000
  | sysTid=11725 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xaf0a0a80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9cf78000-0x9cf7a000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x00efe361> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x00efe361> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"RxComputationThreadPool-4" tid=17 Waiting 
"RxComputationThreadPool-4" daemon prio=5 tid=17 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00dd0 self=0xaf069400
  | sysTid=11728 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xaf0a0d00
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=26 stm=9 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9cd70000-0x9cd72000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x2a6ab347> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x2a6ab347> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"pool-3-thread-1" tid=18 Waiting 
"pool-3-thread-1" prio=5 tid=18 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c00f18 self=0xb47e2800
  | sysTid=11732 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9c81b580
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=11 stm=3 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9cc6c000-0x9cc6e000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x01f82774> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x01f82774> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"HikeHandlerUtil" tid=20 Native 
"HikeHandlerUtil" prio=5 tid=20 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c011b8 self=0xb47e3800
  | sysTid=11736 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9c81b080
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1812 stm=327 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9c5fa000-0x9c5fc000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000003be40  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  #01  pc 0000000000015923  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+26)
  #02  pc 0000000000015931  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+6)
  #03  pc 00000000000127cf  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+98)
  #04  pc 00000000000129f9  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+92)
  #05  pc 0000000000089149  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvi+22)
  #06  pc 00000000000b780b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:143)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:130)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
"WorkManager-WorkManagerTaskExecutor-thread-0" tid=22 Waiting 
"WorkManager-WorkManagerTaskExecutor-thread-0" prio=5 tid=22 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c01270 self=0xb47e4800
  | sysTid=11752 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9c81ba80
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=106 stm=48 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9c1f2000-0x9c1f4000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x09c80d12> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x09c80d12> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"pool-6-thread-1" tid=23 Waiting 
"pool-6-thread-1" prio=5 tid=23 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c013c8 self=0xb47e4000
  | sysTid=11754 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9c81d880
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9beee000-0x9bef0000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0c153ce3> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x0c153ce3> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"arch_disk_io_1" tid=25 Waiting 
"arch_disk_io_1" prio=5 tid=25 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c01be0 self=0xaf06d800
  | sysTid=11768 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xaf0a3280
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=8 stm=3 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9b43d000-0x9b43f000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x38db655b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x38db655b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
"AsyncTask #1" tid=26 Waiting 
"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=26 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x22c01c90 self=0xb47e8c00
  | sysTid=11771 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9c81e780
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x9bd51000-0x9bd53000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x3a6766d1> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor (Thread.java:1220)
- locked <0x3a6766d1> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: have you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the above stack trace points to `SystemAlarmService`. How are you initializing WorkManager ?